# Exception program not showing errors or warnings. Not displaying in console

Tags: exception, console

The following code didn't show any error or warnings There is nothing displaying in console. What is the reason behind this?

```
public class ExceptionDemo {

    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        for (int i=5;i<0;i--)
        {
            System.out.println(10/i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop starts with `i = 5`. Then the condition `i < 0` is evaluated. As `i` is not smaller than zero, the condition evaluates to `false` and the code inside the loop is never executed.